# How to sort NSOrderedSet by date in Swift

Tags: swift, nsorderedset

I'm trying to sort a NSOrderedSet of an entity called Log which has 3 attributes (logDate, logDescription, logThumbnail) by date using NSSortDescriptor but it doesn't work.

```
if let logs = projectSelected?.logs {
        let sd = NSSortDescriptor(key: "logDate", ascending: false)
        logs.sortedArrayUsingDescriptors([sd])
}
```

I have also tried to use projectLogs?.sortInPlace{$0.logDate!.compare($1.logDate!) == .OrderedAscending} to no success. What is the best solution for what I'm trying to do? Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2):

To sort an `NSOrderedSet` in place it must be mutable (`NSMutableOrderedSet`)

```
let mutableLogs = logs.mutableCopy()
let sd = NSSortDescriptor(key: "logDate", ascending: false)
mutableLogs.sortUsingDescriptors([sd])
```

Comment: Thanks this was exactly what I was looking for. Although I'm not sure if this is a glitch, if I reorder an item to the top without a log thumbnail, it will show the log thumbnail of the below item. Refreshing the tableview doesn't fix this problem, I have to change views and reload the table entirely. Any ideas?